# Base58Check encoding: Using for Version 4 UUID?

Tags: base58check, encoding

**Can Base58Check encoding be used to encode a Version 4 UUID?**

This would be handy for the same reasons as encoding Bitcoin public keys in *Base58Check* instead of *Base64*.

I've read the Bitcoin wiki pages on [address encoding](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding) and the [list of address prefixes](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes), but it isn't clear whether *Base58Check* encoding can be used reliably for [version 4 UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) without reserving a prefix somehow. For example, **`U`** for UUID.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is preventing any sort of data from using `Base58Check` encoding, but I'm not sure why you would want to. There's already a multitude of 'altcoins' using a variety of address prefixes though, so you might run into issues should one of them become a real-world success.

In reality, I'd just avoid having users typing a UUID-type string at all, then you don't need to worry about having the typing friendly characters and checksum.

Comment: None of the other Base58Check address schemes are simple UUIDs, but rather some hash or key preservation scheme. UUIDs in and of themselves don't contain a check digit or avoid similar looking characters. Typing in long strings, be they UUIDs or Bitcoin addresses, is tiresome for users but I can't anticipate how they choose to propagate a UUID so I should make value transcription slightly easier and more robust with Base58Check. Obviously transferring without human error (TCP/IP, QR Codes, SDCard, etc) is preferable but not guaranteed.

Comment: My point was that having the same version as an address of an altcoin could be confusing, as they would both look remarkably similar to the user.

Comment: Yes, similarity is an unavoidable byproduct of pseudorandom values; as any item looks much like another. Some degree of visual distinction could be gained by prefixing "UUID-" in the same manner that BitMessages prefix "BM-" but the question of whether the Base58Check address ecology requires "registration" [or equivalent](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/15241/when-why-is-it-easier-to-beg-forgiveness-than-ask-permission) still remains :-)